# Inline CSS style doesn't overwrite the internal style for an echoed WooCommerce product price

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress page to show two specific WooCommerce product prices. I need to assign different colors to them too. So in my Oxygen Builder I created a code block and typed this code for the first product (Product ID = 100):

```
        <style>
        span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
          font-size: 38px;
          color: #6682e8;    
        }      
        </style> 

        <?PHP
        $product_id = 100; 
        $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        echo wc_price($_product->get_price_including_tax(), array('decimals' => 0));
        //this line is just to show the price incl. tax and to round it up so it shows decimals
        ?>
```

The internal  above is to overwrite the default style from WooCommerce. This code works great but when I created another code block and used the code below to show and change the color of my second product (Product ID = 101), I found the inline CSS didn't overwrite the internal style above. It still showed the same color (#6682e8) as the first product.

```
        <div style="color:#FFFFFF;">
        <?PHP
        $product_id = 101; 
        $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        echo wc_price($_product->get_price_including_tax(), array('decimals' => 0));
        ?>
        </div>
```

How come? I've tried different ways to make it happen but none of them worked.

Comment: In CSS, the rule with the most specific selector is applied. In your case `div` is the container so it will never override the color of `span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount`, not even using `!important` on the div rule as it is not the same element but the container. You should modify the selector by adding a parent id or parent class to make it specific to one element only.

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo for pointing that out. Apparently it's my lack of CSS knowledge that causes this issue. :) I'll learn more about all this basic stuff so I can solve similar issues in the future. Cheers.